# Using Vue and AngularJS Together

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

Can we use AngularJS with Vue? As Vue is more like a library than a framework so what are pros and cons of using them together?

Comment: If you use them in 2 separate parts of your application thats fine i guess, I don't see why go this way unless you really have some functionality in one that you can't get from the other. In terms of what you can do with it, you have vue-resource / voux / vue-cli / components / vue-router for creating a full SPA, if you want angular you have angular-cli / components / $http / redux (or any other state management tool) etc... I don't see a reason to use both but You can definitely do that.

Comment: @AfikDeri: of you want to switch from Angular1 to Vue for performance reasons you could use both together while migrating from one to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Angular with Vue.  However, there isn't any reason to use both Vue and Angular 1 in same web app and certainly not in the same page.

As AfikDeri pointed out you probably won't notice any functionality differences.

You're correct in pointing out that Vue is more like a library but Angular 1 can also be used as a library so the decision is largely which one you're more comfortable with or see as more valuable long term.  The comparison between Vue and Angular becomes more pronounced when you consider Angular version 2 (which is much harder to use as a library).